# function doesn't work within the firebase Auth with Angular

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angular7

I'm trying to use Firebase Auth with my Angular7 app.
I want to use some function to process user data.
However after I login with google account, codes until myFunction works,
but after myFunction doesn't work
I'm not sure the root cause as no message was shown.

Could you please advice to me?

```
constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}

public myFunction(obj: any){
  console.log(obj)
}

public socialLogin() {
  var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  this.afAuth.auth.useDeviceLanguage();
  this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
    console.log('logged in'); <- work!
    var user = result.user; <- work!
    console.log(user) <- work!
    this.myFunction(user); <- not work
    console.log('test'); <- not work
  })
```

typescript version is 2.9.2

Comment: Could it be that `this` doesn't refer to the class from within the callback? Try adding a `const self = this;` at the top of `socialLogin()` and instead run `self.myFunction(user);`. Not sure if it will work, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use an arrow function (to inherit the enclosing context), in your code the callback is bound to a different `this`

```
this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(result => {
    console.log('logged in'); <- work!
    var user = result.user; <- work!
    console.log(user) <- work!
    this.myFunction(user); <- not work
    console.log('test'); <- not work
  })
```